# Inconsistency of Equations while finding Velocity in Satellite projection from one planet to another

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, work, conservative-field

#### Here's a question that's creating some doubt to me.

Suppose there are 2 big spheres **A** and **B** of mass M and mass 4M, each of radius, R separated by a distance of 6R.
An object of mass, m is projected from the surface of **A**. What should be the minimum velocity of the body with which it should be projected so that it just reaches the surface of **B**.

[image: Figure of the question]

#### A try to the question:-

We'll first find the neutral point where the gravitational forces by both the objects cancel out each other.
For this, we give a little displacement to the object/satellite, $d\vec{r}$ which is in direction from **A** to **B**.
Also, a unit vector $\hat{r}$ is assigned in the same direction.
Suppose the gravitational forces of the masses be $\vec{F_A}$ and $\vec{F_B}$. They are given below:

$\vec{F_A}$ = - $G\frac{Mm}{r^2}\hat{r}$
$\vec{F_B}$ = $G\frac{4Mm}{x^2}\hat{r}$

Negative sign is not present in $\vec{F_B}$ because $\hat{r}$ is in the direction of the force $\vec{F_B}$.

Now, at neutral point, P

$\vec{F_A}$ = - $\vec{F_B}$
F<sub>A</sub> = F<sub>B</sub>

$G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$ = $G\frac{4Mm}{x^2}$ [Here, *x=6R-r*]
$G\frac{Mm}{r^2}$ = $G\frac{4Mm}{(6R-r)^2}$

4 r<sup>2</sup> = (6R-r)<sup>2</sup>

r = 2R

From this point, P(r=2R), the gravitational force, F<sub>B</sub> is sufficient to attract the satellite to reach the surface of B.

Let W<sub>A</sub> and W<sub>B</sub> be the work done by the gravitational forces $\vec{F_A}$ and $\vec{F_B}$ separately from the surface of A to point P.

---

#### Work done by Force, F<sub>A</sub>:-

dW<sub>A</sub> = $\vec{F_A}\cdot d\vec{r}$
dW<sub>A</sub> = F<sub>A</sub> dr cos 180°

**dW<sub>A</sub> = - F<sub>A</sub> dr ---------Eq(a)**

In equation a,

For limits,
Now, when object is at surface of A, **r = R**
And, when object is at neutral point P, **r = 2R**

$$\int \, dW_A = \int\limits_{R}^{2R} - F_A \, dr$$
$$W_A = - \int\limits_{R}^{2R} G\frac{Mm}{r^2} \, dr$$
$$W_A = -GMm \int\limits_{R}^{2R} \frac{1}{r^2} \, dr$$
$$W_A = -GMm \biggl[\frac{-1}{r}\biggr]_{R}^{2R} $$
$$W_A = -GMm \biggl[\frac{-1}{2R}-\frac{-1}{R}\biggr] $$
$$W_A = -\frac{GMm}{2R} $$

$$W_A = {\color{violet}{\int\limits_{R}^{2R} - F_A \, dr}} = {\color{pink}{-\frac{GMm}{2R}}} $$

Both equations, *violet* and the *pink* one are satisfying each other, infering that the work done by the gravitational force $\vec{F_A}$ will be **negative**.

---

#### Work done by Force, F<sub>B</sub>:-

dW<sub>B</sub> = $\vec{F_B}\cdot d\vec{r}$
dW<sub>B</sub> = F<sub>B</sub> dr cos 0°

**dW<sub>B</sub> = F<sub>B</sub> dr ---------Eq(b)**

In equation b,

For limits,
Now, when object is at surface of A, **r = R -----> x = 6R - r = 5R**
And, when object is at neutral point P, **r = 2R -----> x = 6R - r = 4R**

$$\int \, dW_B = \int\limits_{R}^{2R} F_B \, dr$$
$$W_B = \int\limits_{R}^{2R} G\frac{4Mm}{(6R - r)^2} \, dr$$
$$W_B = 4GMm\int\limits_{5R}^{4R} \frac{1}{x^2} \, dr$$
$$W_B = 4GMm \biggl[\frac{-1}{x} \biggr]_{5R}^{4R} $$
$$W_B = 4GMm \biggl[\frac{-1}{4R}-\frac{-1}{5R}\biggr] $$
$$W_B = 4GMm \biggl[\frac{-1}{20R} \biggr] $$
$$W_B = -\frac{GMm}{5R} $$

$$W_B = {\color{orange}{\int\limits_{R}^{2R} F_B \, dr}} = {\color{cyan}{-\frac{GMm}{5R}}}$$

#### So, here's my doubt:-

The *orange* equation infer that the work by gravitational force $\vec{F_B}$ is **positive** (why) as it was derived from **equation (b)** and in that equation, the angle between force $\vec{F_B}$ and displacement $d\vec{r}$ was 0°. And, it is equal to the *cyan* equation.
But in the *cyan* equation, there is a **negative** sign which tells us that the work by gravitational force $\vec{F_B}$ is **negative**.

Hence, the *orange* equation is **not consistent** with **cyan** equation.

#### My Doubt: Why?

Well, there's lot to be done as we need to find the velocity of satellite with which it should be projected. But, before that, I need to add the 2 work, W<sub>A</sub> and W<sub>B</sub> and make it equal to the kinetic energy of the satellite to find the velocity of the body *(if I'm not wrong)*.

But, I'm stuck here. So please help.

OK, I have done a lot in the post but the doubt is lot like similar to the last one asked in this post [Work Done by Gravitational Force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/368294/work-done-by-gravitational-force).
The difference is only that in that post, I had some problem associated to the direction of radial vector $d\vec{r}$. But here, I don't think so, there's any problem with that.

So, please tell me why the the *orange* equation is **not consistent** with **cyan** equation?

Comment: If you are using $x=6R-r$ in form two, shouldn't it be $dx=-dr$?

Comment: @Kyle Kanos, please refer to the comment given in eranreches answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your transition between the following two equations

$$W_B = \int\limits_{R}^{2R} G\frac{4Mm}{(6R - r)^2} \, dr$$
$$W_B = 4GMm\int\limits_{5R}^{4R} \frac{1}{x^2} \, dr$$

you've forgotten a minus sign due to $dr=-dx$.

Comment: yeah, you are right. I made a mistake. But if you look, $d\vec{r}$ = $-d\vec{x}$. Both are vectors, equal and **opposite in direction** . So, dr cannot be equal to -dx because both are length vector and length cannot have a negative value.

Comment: $dx$ isn't simply length. It is the differential. Loosely speaking, when $r$ increases ($dr>0$) $x$ decreases ($dx<0$), since $x=6R-r$, and thus $dr=-dx$.

Comment: so sorry. I completely ignored this fact. Just now, it hits my head. Thanks for sorting me out in both the posts. Vlauable answer. Thanks!!!!